# Has Json tag but not exported

Tags: json, go

Begining to study golang.
Task: Get Json and Unmarshall it.
But I get mistake:

```
Json tag but not exported
```

How to make unexported fields become exported and then implement it using methods?

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Time struct {
    time
}
type time struct {
    id                    string  `json:"$id"`
    currentDateTime       string  `json:"currentDateTime,string"`
    utcOffset             float64 `json:"utcOffset,string"`
    isDayLightSavingsTime bool    `json:"isDayLightSavingsTime,string"`
    dayOfTheWeek          string  `json:"dayOfTheWeek,string"`
    timeZoneName          string  `json:"timeZoneName,string"`
    currentFileTime       float64 `json:"currentFileTime,string"`
    ordinalDate           string  `json:"ordinalDate,string"`
    serviceResponse       string  `json:"serviceResponse,string"`
}

func (t *Time) GetTime() (Time, error) {
    result := Time{}

    return result, t.Timenow(result)
}
func (t *Time) Timenow(result interface{}) error {

    res, err := http.Get("http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot get Json", err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot create Body", err)
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    var resultJson interface{}
    return json.Unmarshal(body, &resultJson)

}

func main() {

    var a Time
    t, err := a.GetTime()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time:", t)
}
```

Please explain in details whats wrong with struct and how to get right response?

Comment: Your struct values need to be exported by having capitalized field names. For example you need to use `CurrentDateTime` instead of `currentDateTime`.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: The [encoding/json](https://godoc.org/encoding/json) documentation explains that fields must be exported.  The specification [describes exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're adding a JSON tag to a field that isn't exported.

Struct fields must start with upper case letter ([exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)) for the JSON package to see their value.

```
struct A struct {
    // Unexported struct fields are invisible to the JSON package.
    // Export a field by starting it with an uppercase letter.
    unexported string

    // {"Exported": ""}
    Exported string

    // {"custom_name": ""}
    CustomName string `json:"custom_name"`
}
```

The underlying reason for this requirement is that the JSON package uses `reflect` to inspect struct fields. Since `reflect` doesn't allow access to unexported struct fields, the JSON package can't see their value.

Comment: I'm learning golang and i was going crazy over the fact that everytime i returned a JSON response it would return empty Objects. Thanks a ton