# update a map whose value is an array of object but get error

Tags: go

I just started learning Golang today. So, I suppose this question is a basic one howerver I tried what I can try, but get error.

So, I have defined a `Student` struct type:

```
type Student struct {
    firstname string    `json:"first_name"`
    id   int `json:"id"`
}
```

I want to have a `map` data structure, in which the map's key represent "class id" & the value of each key in this `map` is an array of `Student`. This is what I have tried:

```
var studentsMap = make(map[int][]Student)

func registerStudent(classId int, studentName string, studentId int) {
   var studentsInClass = studentsMap[classId]
   if studentsInClass == nil {
       studentsInClass = []Student{}
   }

   // append the new student to the studentsInClass array   
   var updatedStudentsArr = append(studentsInClass, Student{studentName, studentId})

   // update the map for this class id with updated array of students
   // Compiler ERROR: Cannot use 'updatedStudentsArr' (type []Student) as the type Student
   studentsMap[classId] = updatedStudentsArr
}
```

As you see in my comment in the code, when I try to update the `studentsMap` with the new array, I get compiler error `Cannot use 'updatedStudentsArr' (type []Student) as the type Student`. Why is that? My guess is that I defined wrongly the `studentsMap` map type, but how to fix?

Comment: Unrelated: Export your fields if you want to JSON a Student.

Comment: The playground code is [here](https://go.dev/play/p/744Z7e6wtgs). This is working,

Comment: @Volker Thanks! For sure I am doing some stupid stuff as it was my day-1 of Go language (Day 2 now). Could you please provide a link or ref or code snippet of how-to regarding to your comment of "Export your field"?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems to be working fine, as pointed out by @nipuna in the comments.

As a small note, when you test for a key,value existence in go you get two values, the latter being a boolean. You can thus use the following to test whether `studentsMap[classId]` exists

```
studentsInClass, ok := studentsMap[classId]
if !ok {
    studentsInClass = []Student{}
}
```

Regarding your second question related to @Volker's comment, you can read more about exporting struct fields in the following answers.

If you are using an IDE, it might be warning you about it (e.g. in VSCode I get `struct field firstname has json tag but is not exported`).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320595/5621318

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129474/5621318

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25595269/5621318